# Is a transaction executed correctly in this query?

Tags: sql, delphi

I am unsure if I wrote this correctly.

```
procedure TMainForm.AdvGlowButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
DataModule2.INS_Query.Close;
DataModule2.INS_Query.SQL.Clear;
DataModule2.FDTransaction1.StartTransaction;
try
if cxlookupcombobox1.Text ='' then begin
....
....
DataModule2.INS_Query.ExecSQL;
DataModule2.FDTransaction1.Commit;
end else  begin
if cxlookupcombobox1.Text <>'' then
......
......
DataModule2.INS_Query.ExecSQL;
DataModule2.FDTransaction1.Commit;
end;
except
on e: exception do begin
Showmessage(format('Error occured. Error is: %s',[e.message]));
DataModule2.FDTransaction1.Rollback;
DataModule2.MYTABLE.Cancel;
end;
end;
```

It executes all right but something is nagging me.

> DataModule2.FDTransaction1.Commit;

Must it be commited twice? Or did I write this query correctly at all?

Comment: In the code you show you can execute only one `DataModule2.FDTransaction1.Commit`. Either inside the main `if` clause or inside the `else` clause. Anyway, it seems a bit strange that the first condition in the `else` clause is the same as the one in the main `if` clause. Is this real code?

Comment: yes,it is real and executes ok as far as I can tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Commit only once for the started transaction. Generally, the code construction in pseudo-code looks like this:

```
Transaction.Start;
try
  Query.Execute;
  Query.Execute;
  ...
  Transaction.Commit;
except
  Transaction.Rollback;
  raise;
end;
```

And since you are commiting only once, your code seems to be correct in this manner.

Comment: You should add a `raise;` after the rollback to get the information why ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo, my pseudo-language does not support re-raising exceptions :-)

Comment: The OP exception handling is showing a message - bad idea. Raising a new exception or just reraise the original is the way to handle this, and the application will show the message.

Comment: @SirRufo, new version of my pseudo-language has been released :)